# How to stop Spark View Engine HTML encoding?

Tags: html-encode, spark-view-engine

Even with the following in spark section of web.config:

```
<pages automaticEncoding="false">
```

Things between `${...}` Still get passed through `H(...)`, which HTML encodes it.

How change this or should I just fall back to `!{...}`?

Comment: `automaticEncoding="false"` helped to me. :/

Answer (score 8):

You can change Spark's default using its configuration, though I would recommend you use `${}` when you want encoded HTML and `!{}` when you don't.

Spark can be configured from either Web.config or using a `SparkSettings` instance.

---

In Web.config, under your `<spark>` configuration, add:

```
<pages automaticEncoding="false">
```

You'll want to make sure you only have the one `<pages/>` element.  I'm unsure if Spark's processor will raise an error if you have multiple.

---

Using `SparkSettings`, add:

```
SparkSettings settings = new SparkSettings()
    .SetAutomaticEncoding(false);
```

---

If you have these settings and still get automatic encoding, set a break-point at the point where you instantiate your `SparkViewFactory` (or use `Console.WriteLine()` or your logging framework) and have a look at:

```
mySparkViewFactory.Settings.AutomaticEncoding
```